# Convert JSON Array to JSON Object (Python)

Tags: python, json

I have an empty JSON Array...

`FINAL_ELOGII_DATA_ARRAY = []`

That gets populated via .append inside a for loop from a Python Object...

```
for ord in FINAL_SHOPIFY_DATA:
    FINAL_ELOGII_DATA_ARRAY.append({
        "date": int(ELOGII_TODAY),
        "customer": str(ord.id),
        "tasks": [
            {
                "date": int(0),
                "customer": str(ord.id),
                "type": int(0),
                "location": {
                    "address": str(ord.shipping_address.address1),
                    "postCode": str(ord.shipping_address.zip),
                    "city": str(ord.shipping_address.city),
                    "country": str(ord.shipping_address.country),
                    "contactName": str(ord.customer.first_name) + ' ' + str(ord.customer.last_name),
                    "contactPhone": str(ord.shipping_address.phone),
                    "contactEmail": str(ord.email),
                    "ref": str(ord.customer.first_name) + ' ' + str(ord.customer.last_name)
                }
            }
        ]
    })
```

And outputs the following (example):

```
[
   {
      "date":####,
      "customer":"######",
      "tasks":[
         {
            "date":0,
            "customer":"######",
            "type":0,
            "location":{
               "address":"######",
               "postCode":"########",
               "city":"#####",
               "country":"#########",
               "contactName":"#########",
               "contactPhone":"########",
               "contactEmail":"",
               "ref":"#######"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

So the JSON array gets populated correctly, however, I need this to be a JSON object rather than an array as the API that I'm posting to doesn't support arrays, only objects. Any tips on converting this to an object?

Comment: `the_object = the_array[0]`?

Comment: @L3viathan That's only getting the first result for me in the array when I have multiple, how would I go about getting the rest?

Comment: _I have an empty JSON Array..._ That looks like a plain Python list to me. Please provide a [mcve], as well as the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Container():
    def __init__(self, listData):
        self.listData = listData

for..
 listToSend.append(data) 

container = Container(listToSend)
```

Comment: Thanks @Suriya - I'm already appending to an array via "FINAL_ELOGII_DATA_ARRAY.append({" above. I need to convert that array to just a list of objects, without the wrapped brackets [].

Comment: Is the length of data content is 1?